# Adding Controls to Controls in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to add a span, inside an anchor, inside a dd tag. for some reason this:

```
protected Control MakeDD() {
    var dd = new HtmlGenericControl("dd");
    var link = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
    var span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");

    link.Controls.Add(span);
    dd.Controls.Add(link);
    return dd;
}
```

only generates

```
<dd><a></a></dd>
```

instead of

```
<dd><a><span></span></a></dd>
```

how do I add controls to a control, then add that control to another control?

Comment: Yo dawg, I heard you like controls so we put a control in your control...

Comment: I dropped your code into a webform and got your expected result.

Comment: I believe the issue was that one of the controls I was attempting to add was actually writing a string instead of creating a control. Someone's custom implementation.. Anywho, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping a panel on a page as the container and doing:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pnlTest.Controls.Add(MakeDD());
        }
```

emits the following on the page:

```
<div id="MainContent_pnlTest">

    <dd><a><span></span></a></dd>
</div>
```

This is asp.net 4

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you set something to the span value, does it show up then?

```
...
var span = new HtmlGenericControl("span");
span.InnerHtml = "test";
link.Controls.Add(span);
...
```